# How can I show/hide a layout in the main activity from a RecyclerView in android studio java?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have an activity which consists of a recycler view for generating buttons (from a different layout file) and a layout with elements for confirmation.

I want to make it so when I click on the button "NEW GAME" (in the Recyclerview class), the confirmationLayout (in the MainMenu Activity) shows. But I can't, can someone help me?

MainMenu Class

```
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView profileIcon;
    private TextView username;

    private RelativeLayout newGameConfirmationLayout;
    private TextView yesButton, noButton;

    private RecyclerView buttonRecyclerView;
    private ButtonRecyclerAdapter adapter;

    private DataHandler dataHandler;

    private ArrayList<String> buttonNames = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

        newGameConfirmationLayout = findViewById(R.id.newGameConfirmationLayout);
        yesButton = findViewById(R.id.yesButton);
        noButton = findViewById(R.id.noButton);

        buttonRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.buttonRecyclerView);
        buttonRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainMenu.this));


        if(General.infoSaved){buttonNames.add("CONTINUE GAME");}

        buttonNames.add("NEW GAME");
        buttonNames.add("CHANGE USER");
        buttonNames.add("PRACTICE");
        buttonNames.add("EXERCISE LIST");

        adapter = new ButtonRecyclerAdapter(buttonNames, MainMenu.this);
        buttonRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        yesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
                startGame();
            }
        });

        noButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                newGameConfirmationLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

    private void startGame(){}

    public void show_confirmationLayout(){
        newGameConfirmationLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

RecyclerView Class

```
public class ButtonRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ButtonRecyclerAdapter.buttonHolder>{

    private ArrayList<String> buttonNames;
    private Context context;
 

    public ButtonRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<String> loginButtonNames, Context context) {
        this.buttonNames = loginButtonNames;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public buttonHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.button_block,parent,false);
        return new buttonHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull buttonHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.button.setText(buttonNames.get(position));

        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String buttonName = holder.button.getText().toString();

                switch (buttonName){

                    case "NEW GAME":
                        
                        MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu();
                        mainMenu.show_confirmationLayout();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return buttonNames.size();
    }

    public class buttonHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private Button button;

        public buttonHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonblock);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding it as a class (as above) but I get the error that the layout is a null object / However when I try to write the ame line of code directly in the activity it works.

Answer (score 0):

There's a method I personally use in my `RecyclerView's` `Adapter` and `ViewHolder` is to set the `width` and `height` of your item's `ViewGroup` to `0`.

Here's the method you can add to your adapter class which takes item position that you want to hide:

```
public void hideFeedItem(int position){
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = getViewHolderAtPosition(position);
        if(holder != null){
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height=0;
            params.width= 0;
            holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
}
```

Where `itemview` is the root `ViewGroup` that should be already defined in your `ViewHolder` in your case should be  `buttonHolder`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem with your answer is that i could hide the buttonholder (which id the layout for the buttons), but i want to hide an element in another layout (MainMenu), the layout where the recyclerview is.